# Django Paginator - all pages objects action

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models, django-rest-framework

Folks,

I'm currently developing a web application using Django and need to replicate a feature that currently exists in the admin section of Django. Namely, there is an option to select objects on all pages and take same action on all these. I have a Paginator on my page, but not sure what would be the best way to tell the server I want to perform an action on all objects, not only these being currently shown. Please advise! Cheers!

[image: Select all entries]

Comment: It's hard to help you if we don't know what action you would like to do and how your code is organized. First thoughts would be to send a boolean which would trigger an if statement on server side, or you could also write another view where you'd send a request and that would be triggered from the frontend...

Comment: Simple flag variable would do fine

Comment: @BriseBalloches, long story short - I was just looking into a way to replicate 'select all' from the admin section and make some action on the selected objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to send a request like that

```json
{
    "all_items": true|false,
    "selected_ids": [23, 45, ....]
}
```

then server side you can check if the field `all_items` is true or not

Comment: Thanks @Massimo, That's the only option that comes to my mind. Wondering if Django admin section does it similar.